# Trouble while installing redis-server

Tags: server, apt, dependencies, redis

So for some reason it seems that the installation of the redis-server that was serving the sidekiq on one of my machines got removed (How does that happen?). I assume this because commands like which redis give blank likes.

I tried reinstalling with apt-get install and apt-get -f install but it keeps giving me this error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
redis-server : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but 1.7~precise1~ppa1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm unsure of how to correct this. Any help woudld be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

i think you are trying to install using sudo `apt-get -f install redis-server` that will not install broken packege dependency.if this not work then try with other repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/redis-server
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

or

open sudo `vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list` and paste

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
```

save it and run command

```
sudo wget -q -O - http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install redis-server
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an older version of this from an PPA. Try to update it by reinstall:
    sudo apt-get purge init-system-helpers
    sudo apt-get install init-system-helpers

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The purge command exits as well with....

the following packages have unmet dependencies:



 nginx-common : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install init-system-helpers=1.22ubuntu11`

Comment: Says that version was not found

Comment: Which version of ubuntu do you use?